# Deserialize Child XML Elements as an XML String

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb, jackson-dataformat-xml

Using either Jackson or JAXB, is there a way to deserialize/marshal an entire subtree of child XML elements into a String?

For example, given the following XML:

```
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar>
      <baz/>
    </bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

Is there a way to deserialize/marshal that to the following class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Root {
    private String foo;

    // constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

where the result would look like `Root(foo="<bar><baz/></bar>")`?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own jackson deserializer for this:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("configModule",   Version.unknownVersion());
    module.addDeserializer(Root.class, new DeSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    // Root readValue = mapper.readValue(<xml source>);
  }
}

class DeSerializer extends StdDeserializer<Root> {

  protected DeSerializer() {
    super(Root.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Root deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws Exception {
    // use p.getText() and p.nextToken to navigate through the xml and construct Root object
    return new Root();

  }
}
```